# Spring Tool Suite: Changes to static resources triggers redeploy

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

I recently got into a problem with STS. It redeploy's my application on all kind of changes (JSP, CSS, JS). It was only triggered on Java changes before I upgraded it to 3.4.0.

What I tried are the following:

- Enable/Disable JMX-Reloading
- Tried both "Automatically publish when resource change" and "Automatically publish after a build event"
- I turned ON/OFF "Auto reloading" for the web module.

But I can only get it to not publish at all or publish on everything.

This slow's down my development process.

How do I get my Spring application to only redeploy on Java changes?

Edit:
If I turn off "Auto reloading" my JSP does not even refresh on change. This is very frustrating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it buy simply removing the server and then add a new one.

1. Right click in servers window.
2. Add -> server
3. VMware -> VMware vFabric tc Server v2.7-2.9
4. Existing instance -> base-instance
5. Finish

I have no clue what the problem was with the first one. Settings where not changed and I couldent find anything suspect.

Comment: Turns out that it is not working when having the base url (root url) in the web module set to '/' also.